# NgOptimizedImage doesn't load dynamic URLs with Error: NG02953

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

This issue does NOT happen with **src**

It's a dating app which users can select a profile photo from their album to show on the navbar.component. When the user logs in, their **main** image is loaded as their profile photo using **ngSrc** with no issue.

**Problem:**
Once the user selects another image from their album as their **main**, the navbar profile photo doesn't get updated with the new photo and Angular throws this Error in the console.
[image: Console Error]

Here's the code which is supposed to be working dynamically in the navbar.component.html.

```
<img ngSrc="{{profilePhotoUrl}}" fill>
```

Angular CLI: 16.1.4

Tried using ChangeDetection but no luck.